# Group By Count and a field in the same query

Tags: sql-server, count, group-by

I have a table (MyTable) with 3 columns; Number, Line, Amount.
If Number is the same in more than 3 records, I want to return these records grouped by Number. Otherwise I want to all other records grouped by Number and Line.

This is what I got so far. It gives an error as Line needs to be in an aggregated function

```
select * (
select Number, (case when count(Line) > 3 then -1 else Line end) as Line2, sum(Amount)
from MyTable
group by Number, Line2
) as x
order by x.Number
```

MyTable looks something like this:

```
Number    Line    Amount
------------------------
1         1       100
1         1       100
1         2       200
1         2       200
2         1       150
2         1       150
3         1       300
3         2       350
```

I want the result look something like this:

```
Number    Line2   Amount
------------------------
1         -1      600    <- More than 3 lines
2         1       300    <- Grouped by Line
3         1       300    
3         2       350
```

Comment: is negative one a default value?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT Number, -1 AS Line, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
FROM mytable
GROUP BY Number 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 3

UNION 

SELECT Number, Line, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
FROM mytable
WHERE Number NOT IN (SELECT Number
                     FROM mytable
                     GROUP BY Number 
                     HAVING COUNT(*) > 3)
GROUP BY Number, Line
```

Comment: in second query, can we just use the less than condition `HAVING COUNT(*) <= 3` to remove `IN`?

Comment: @EuphoriaGrogi I think not, because the grouping is different in this case.

Comment: ahh i see, im just curious :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use CTE like this:

```
DECLARE @t table
(Number int,Line int,Amount int)

INSERT @t VALUES
  (1,1,100),(1,1,100),(1,2,200),
  (1,2,200),(2,1,150),(2,1,150),
  (3,1,300),(3,2,350)

;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT 
    Number, Line, Amount, 
    count(*) over (partition by number) cnt
FROM @t
)
SELECT
  Number, 
  CASE WHEN cnt < 3 THEN Line ELSE -1 END Line2,
  SUM(Amount) Amount
FROM CTE
GROUP BY number, CASE WHEN cnt < 3 THEN Line ELSE -1 END
```

Result:

```
Number  Line    Amount
1       -1      600
2       1       300
3       1       300
3       2       350
```